# Partitions using only powers of two on $1000.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, generating-functions, integer-partitions

> How many ways are there to write $1000$ as a sum of powers of $2,$ ($2^0$ counts), where each power of two can be used a maximum of $3$ times. Furthermore, $1+2+4+4$ is the same as $4+2+4+1$. These count as one arrangement, not two separate ones.

To clarify, the ways to write $4$ as a sum of powers are:

$4=4, 2+2=4, 1+2+1.$

I think these go up in increments of $2,$ for example the ways to write $8$ is 5...etc. so it would just be the 1000th term of that sequence, but I may be missing something. How would I start this problem?

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A008619](https://oeis.org/A008619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a recurrence.  If $n$ is odd, you need an odd number of $1$ terms, so write down a $1$ and consider $n-1$ in what follows.  If $n$ is even, you can either use $0$ or $2\ 1$s.  If you use $2\ 1$s, you have $n-2$ left to express and can't use any $1$s, so you can express $\frac 12(n-2)$ and multiply all the terms by $2$.  If you don't use any $1$s, you can express $\frac n2$ and multiply all the terms by $2$.  So if $a(n)$ is the number of ways to express $n$ we have $$a(n)=\begin{cases}1&n=1\\2&n=2\\a(\frac n2)+a(\frac{n}2-1)&n \text{ even}\\a(n-1)&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
Rob Pratt finds that the solution is $a(n)=1+\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$.  This works for $1,2$.  Then if it works up through even $n$, $a(n+1)=a(n)=1+\lfloor \frac {n+1}2 \rfloor, a(n+2)=a(\frac n2+1)+a(\frac n2)=1+\lfloor \frac{\frac n2+1}2\rfloor+1+\lfloor \frac{\frac n2}2\rfloor=1+\lfloor \frac {n+2}2\rfloor$

Comment: So we have $a(1000)=a(500)+a(499)?$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  At the other end, $a(4)=a(2)+a(1)$ where the $a(2)$ is the two sums that do not involve $1$s and the $a(1)$ comes from using two $1$s and a $2$ for the rest.

Comment: But then we'd have to calculate $a(500)$ and $a(499)$ right?

Comment: Yes, this is a recursion.  Then $a(500)=a(250)+a(249), a(499)=a(498)=a(249)+a(248)$ and so on

Comment: So we basically just calculate it again and again, right?

Comment: This recursion yields explicit formula $a(n)=1+\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Comment: How did you get that explicit formula, and it would bring us to $a(1000)=1+500=\boxed{501},$ if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: I would find it by computing the first ten or so terms, noticing the formula, and prove it works by induction.

Comment: @RobPratt:  may I edit that in to my answer with attribution?

Comment: @RossMillikan, certainly.

Comment: @RossMillikan Computing it seems kind've "brute force." Is there a slicker way, or would that be the best way for recursions.

Comment: @FrostBite: Computing the first few values by hand to get an idea of the behavior of the sequence is almost always a good idea when it’s feasible.

Comment: @RossMillikan: This is OEIS [$A008619$](https://oeis.org/A008619).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  you got MathJax in the last instead of a link

Comment: @RossMillikan: It works for me as a link. (It’s also MathJax.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I tried to right click it to open in a new tab as I was editing my response.    I got the Show Math As window

Comment: @RossMillikan: It works as a link if you click on it. I routinely open in a new tab by holding down the control key and clicking on the link, so that problem didn’t occur to me, but I see that you’re right: the Show Math As window overrides the usual menu. I’ll have to remember that in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The generating function is
\begin{align}
&(1+x+x^2+x^3)
(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)
(1+x^4+x^8+x^{12})
\dots \\
&= \prod_{k=0}^\infty (x^{0\cdot 2^k}+x^{1\cdot 2^k}+x^{2\cdot 2^k}+x^{3\cdot 2^k}) \\
&= \prod_{k=0}^\infty ((x^{2^k})^0+(x^{2^k})^1+(x^{2^k})^2+(x^{2^k})^3) \\
&= \prod_{k=0}^\infty (1+x^{2^k})(1+x^{2^{k+1}}) \\
&= \prod_{k=0}^\infty (1+x^{2^k}) \prod_{k=0}^\infty (1+(x^2)^{2^k}) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2} \quad \text{by uniqueness of binary representation}\\
&= \frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^2} \\
&= \frac{1/4}{1+x} + \frac{1/4}{1-x} + \frac{1/2}{(1-x)^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n  + \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies explicit formula
$$\frac{1}{4}(-1)^n  + \frac{1}{4}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2}(n+1) = 
\frac{2n+3+(-1)^n}{4}=\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{2}\right\rfloor=1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor.$$
In particular, $n=1000$ yields $501$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that counts via an explicit bijection.

**Claim:** The number of ways is equal to the number of solutions to $ n = a + 2b$, where $a, b$ are non-negative integers.

**Corollary:** There are $ 1 + \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ ways.

**Genearlize this:** Show that the number of ways of expressing $n$ as the sum of powers of two each used a maximum of 7 times, is equal to the number of ways of writing $n = a + 2b + 4c $, where $a, b, c$ are non-negative integers.

**Proof of claim:** We show the bijection between ways to express $n$ as sum of powers of $2$ at most 3 times and representations $n = a+b$ by creating the map in each direction.

Given a representation $n = a+2b$,
There is a unique way to express $a$ in binary, which determines the powers of 2.
There is a unique way to express $b$ in binary, which we will use to determine the powers of 2 that appear twice (or more).
For example, with $ 1000 = 124 + 2 \times 418$, we have
$a = 124 =  1111100_2 = 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 $
$b = 418 = 110110110_2 = 2^8 + 2^7 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^2 + 2^1.  $
Then, we have $ 1000 = a + 2b = 2\times 2^8 + 2 \times 2^7 + 2^6 + 3 \times 2^5 + 3 \times 2^4 + 2^3 + 3\times 2^2 + 2 \times 2^1$ gives a way of writing 1000 as the sum of powers of 2, each used at most 3 times.

Conversely, given a valid way, we can split it up into our $a$ and $b$ parts, corresponding to the number of terms. Namely

- If the power of 2 appears 0 times, it goes into neither.
- If the power of 2 appears 1 times, it goes into $a$
- If the power of 2 appears 2 times, it goes into $b$.
- If the power of 2 appears 3 times, it goes into $a$ and $b$.

Note: The better way to write this, is to condition on the binary digits. Namely, if the power of 2 appears $k$ times, then it goes into $a$ if the "units digit" is 1, and get into $b$ if the "tens digit" is 1.
This helps with the generalization.

To check that you understand this,

- Reverse the worked example.
- Verify that we yield $ n = a + b$.
- Verify that the composition of both maps yields the identify.

Hence, we have a bijection and the exact number of ways is $ 1 + \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$.